# Is Paypal Adaptive Payment API depreached

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are researching a way to automatically pay the developers of e-commerce modules we sell on our web shop. A lot of reading suggest the Paypal Adaptive Parallel Payment should be the solution. But Paypal developer docs seem to say that this API is now restricted and no option. If so, is there a new API from Paypal. The Braintree marketplace is no option for us in Europe

Comment: 'Depreached'? Do you mean 'deprecated'?

Answer (score 0):

Express Checkout supports parallel payments as well -- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/

Comment: From Paypal developer documents
Express Checkout - NVP/SOAP (Deprecated)

Comment: In this instance, "deprecated" just means "we're not adding any new features to this product".  Right now, we don't have anything else that supports parallel payments.  Plus, Express Checkout isn't restricted like Adaptive Payments is.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Cole for the clarification!

Comment: When I go through the docs from Paypal it seems that we perhaps has misunderstood the paralell payments It seems that the sender will get the recipients named in the overview. 
What we try to accomplish is a way to keep a commission for the sale and send the rest of the payment to the app developer in this case.

Comment: Yes, you are correct -- with Parallel Payments, the sender will see that they are making separate payments to each of the parties named in the transaction.  If you want a way for a buyer to make a payment and take a fee behind the scenes, Chained Payments (part of Adaptive Payments) would be the best way to do that.  Unfortunately, Adaptive Payments is deprecated; we're working on a replacement for it, but it's not ready just yet.

Comment: @MattCole This is an old thread.  I am looking to use the PayPal Adaptive Payment method but just found out that it is deprecated.  It's been almost 3 years now, has Paypal not come up with a replacement?  I have been using Paypal for decades for simple membership payment but now I need to allow members to sell stuff so that I can take a commission.  But now I am stuck if Paypal don't offer this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Adaptive Payments are still supported now. You may try access below page to apply for an APP ID. If your application is approved, you may still continue integrate with Adaptive Payments.

https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications

Comment: Thanks. We will use another provider until Paypal come up with something